# Query a nested search in mongodb without dot notation from enduser

Tags: python, mongodb, search, nosql, mongodb-query

For an end-user application I need to build a GUI to search for values in mongodb documents.
I have the following document:

```
{'METADATA': {'AttachmentSchema': None,
              'DataSchema': None,
              'Tags': {'AcquisitionTime': '2019-02-05T15:59:37.5862118Z',
                       'DetectorState': {'CameraState': {'ApplyCameraProfile': 'false',
                                                         'ApplyImageOrientation': 'true',
                                                         'ExposureTime': '2200000',
                                                         'Frame': '0,0,2752,2208',
                                                         'ImageOrientation': '3'}},
                       'FocusPosition': '+000000002097.2550',
                       'ImageScaling': {'ImageScaling': {'ImagePixelSize': '4.54,4.54'}},
                       'RoiCenterOffsetX': '+000000000000.0000',
                       'RoiCenterOffsetY': '+000000000000.0000',
                       'StageXPosition': '+000000141526.5820',
                       'StageYPosition': '+000000189329.5000'}},
 '_id': ObjectId('5def7e8c4802b906dd067f97')}
```

How can I access the key e.g. `ImageOrientation` with the value `3`.
With the dot notation is very simple like that:

```
db.getCollection("dy").find(
    { 
        "METADATA.Tags.DetectorState.CameraState.ImageOrientation" : "3"
    }
);
```

But the non-IT user cannot write this query, so I want as Input from the user as Key ImageOrientation and as value the 3 and build in the backend the query for the user and give the results to the python gui back. I tried it with the `$elemMatch` operator, but it dont work on this case.

Otherwise I have to build in reverse the dot-notation query for the user, but I think thats not a good idea. Because the document structure can be various.

Answer (score 0):

Please use aggregate with match condition

```
db.getCollection("dy").aggregate({$match:{"METADATA.Tags.DetectorState.CameraState.ImageOrientation" : "3" }})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

Comment: thats not the scope of this question. In my opinion this here needs a solution to build a query without the dot notation. Because the enduser will not know which parent keys have the searched key.

Comment: sorry, may be impossible because we must know path of search key